# Angular Materials: growing grid

Tags: angular, angular-material, postman

I’m looking for a tool in Angular Materials like a growing grid. What I mean by growing grid is a grid or a table in which the user can enter information into the last row and it automatically produces a new (empty) row under it.

As an example, look at Postman and go to the body tab:

[image: Postman]

If I enter a key/value pair in the table, all of a sudden a new empty row shows up underneath it:

[image: Postman - new row]

Is there a tool in Angular Materials that will do this?